# Generate Sorbet RBI files with bundler and dependabot

Tags: sorbet

I'm trying to add Sorbet to a Rails codebase maintained by 20 engineers. We use dependabot to update gems pretty frequently and I'd rather not have to manually run `srb rbi update` on every version bump. Is there a way to automatically run `srb rbi update` every time `bundle install` is run, and have it only update gems that have been changed (so it doesn't take 5 minutes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run every piece of code from every gem for Sorbet to create accurate type information, unfortunately, so only updating specific gems isn't really possible.

You could theoretically write a script that runs the `srb rbi update` command and then generates a git patch file and opens a PR/MR automatically, but I don't really know of any tool to do that.

I use Dependabot for my Rails app and so far what I've been doing is just running the update command every once in a while. Most of the time, having slightly outdated method definitions isn't going to cause type errors for new versions unless the gem's codebase changes completely.